# How would I loop a randomly generated arithmetic 10 times over? this is my code so far

Tags: python, random

```
import random 
score = 0
ops = ['+','-','*']
num1 = random.randint(1,9)
num2 = random.randint(1,9)
operation = random.choice(ops)
print(num1)
print(operation)
print(num2)
user = int(input(""))
if operation == "+":
    answer = num1 + num2
elif operation == "-":
    answer = num1 - num2
elif operation == "*":
    answer = num1 * num2

if user == answer:
    print("correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
        print("Incorrect")
print (score)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to explain exactly what you want this program to return, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that i have to generate 10 random questions for a basic arithmetic quiz. The code works I am just confused as to how to generate 10 questions because the code as it stands generates 1 and then ends. Thanks.

Comment: Try looking up loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a for loop that iterate 10 times over your code.

```
import random 
score = 0
ops = ['+','-','*']

for i in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(1,9)
    num2 = random.randint(1,9)
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    print(num1)
    print(operation)
    print(num2)
    user = int(input(""))
    if operation == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operation == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operation == "*":
        answer = num1 * num2

    if user == answer:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    print (score)
```

Comment: thankyou, i should try to look up how for loops work xD. Ty buddy.